# Проблема с односвязним списком

Tags: c++, указатели, структуры, список

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с такой задачей. Нужно инициализировать односвязный список, ввести его с клавиатуры и вывести. Перепробовал все способы. Но почему-то при выводе списка выводится только первый элемент. Может кто знает как исправить?

Заранее благодарю

P.S. Данные в списке представлены в виде структуры. И заранее не известно сколько пользователь введет элементов списка

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

//List #1
struct A
{
    int cyfra;
    char symbol;
};

struct List
{
    A a;
    List* next;
};

void Init(List** b)
{
    (*b) = new List;
    List *end = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            cin >> (*b)->a.cyfra >> (*b)->a.symbol;
            (*b)->next = NULL;
            end = (*b);
        }
        else {
            end->next = new List;
            cin >> end->a.cyfra >> end->a.symbol;
            end = end->next;
            end->next = NULL;
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN))break;
    }

}

void Print(List *b)
{
    List *print = b;
    cout << endl;
    while (print != NULL)
    {
        cout << print->a.cyfra << print->a.symbol << " ";
        print = print->next;
    }
}

void main()
{

    //Initial L prim
    List* begin = NULL;
    Init(&begin);

    cout << "List: ";
    Print(begin);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос,  но все же любопытно: для чего вы  в функцию Init(List** b)  передаете указатель на указатель?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Скорее всего потому,  что человек еще не знает про ссылку на указатель.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan если, б я изменил там ссылку ето не решило б мою проблему

Comment: @Igor,  может и так,  а может и другая причина.  Я, например, встречал людей, который спрашивали:  для чего ссыльки нужны, когда с таким же успехом можно работать и с указательями?.. К стати и в   SO я встречал вопрос  такого рода содержания...

Comment: @T. Gryts, нет у вас никакой проблемы.  Ошибка найдется

Comment: Итераторы попробуйте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Односвязные списки это очень простая штука. Главное, чтобы код, работающий с ними, был структурирован в соответствии с шагами алгоритма (КО -)).

Вашу задачу совершенно логично решает вот такой `main`:

```
int main () {
  // Получить заполненный список
  List *list = get_list();

  // поэлементно распечатать его
  cout << "List:\n";
  for (List *p = list; p; p = p->next)
    cout << p->a.cyfra << p->a.symbol << ' ';
}
```

Вы совершенно правильно решили, что при последовательном построении списка в порядке поступления его элементов, нужно запомнить адрес первого элемента списка и иметь указатель на его последний элемент.

Вот так может выглядеть функция, которая последовательно строит список:

```
List *get_list () {
  List *head = get_AList_item(), // взять первый элемент списка
       *tail = head;             // сейчас он же и последний в списке

  if (head) 
    while ((tail->next = get_AList_item())) // обратите внимание, здесь мы автоматически получаем обнуленный указатель на следующий у последнего элемента списка
      tail = tail->next;

  return head;  // тут накопили весь список
}
```

Думаю, что функцию (`get_AList_item()`), реализующую ввод данных и выделяющую память под каждый элемент вы сами легко напишете.

В качестве простого ее примера:

```
List * get_AList_item () {
  List *elem = new List;

  if (cin >> elem->a.cyfra >> elem->a.symbol) 
    return elem;

  delete elem;
  return 0;
}
```

Как видите, вся прелесть простых задач, реализуемых с односвязными списками в том, что на каждом шаге декомпозиции программы, благодаря тривиальности односвязных списков, мы имеем функции с минимумом строк кода, оперирующих списком. Но есть и оборотная сторона медали -- далеко не все операции с такими списками имеют эффективные алгоритмы.

Comment: и решать задачу несколькими способами  положительно влияет на процесс изучения. Все верно...

Comment: @avp спасибо за рабочий вариант и понятное объяснение

Comment: Вот еще один вопрос возник. Когда вводиш список. То в конце чтобы input прекратился нужно написать какой-нибудь / или . тогда вызывается функция вывода. Но как сделать чтобы вывод происходил после нажатия enter?

Comment: Нажатие ENTER отделяет одну *строку* ввода от другой. Т.о. вам надо несколько изменить структуру ввода. Например, в начале `get_list()` можно прочесть всю строку (функцией `getline(cin, s)`). Затем можно сделать поток чтения из строки `istringstream ss(s)` и передавать его в модифицированную  `get_Alist_item(istringstream &scin)`, а там уже читать из этого потока, а не из cin

Answer (score 3):

```
  else {
            end->next = new List;
            end = end->next; // 
            cin >> end->a.cyfra >> end->a.symbol; // тут           
            end->next = NULL;
```

такой вариант пробуйте.

И еще,  в любом случаи правильнее будет в конструкторе класса  `list` сразу инициализировать `next` нулем, чтоб в коде каждый раз не делать это в ручную...

```
struct A
{
    int cyfra;
    char symbol;
};

struct List
{
    A a;
    List* next;
    List() : next(0) {a.cyfra = 0; a.symbol = '8';}
    ~List() {delete next;}
};

  void Init(List*& b)
{
    b = new List;
    List *end = b;
    while (cin >> end->a.cyfra >> end->a.symbol) {
        end->next = new List;
        end = end->next;
    }
}
void Print(List *b)
{
    List *print = b;
    cout << endl;
    while (print->next)
    {
        cout << print->a.cyfra  << " " << print->a.symbol << " ";
        print = print->next;
    }
}
int main()
{  
    List* begin = NULL;
    Init(begin);
    cout << "List: ";
    Print(begin);
    return 0;
}
```

Этот код работает как надо...

Comment: Пришлось немного улучшать  код в функциях

Comment: А  по большому счету  я бы написал это совсем иначе, или  только класс А  и код с std::list

Comment: Отлично работает! Спасибо

Comment: главное, чтоб вы понели как   работает....

Answer (score 0):

```
        end->next = new List;
        cin >> end->next->a.cyfra >> end->next->a.symbol;
```

Comment: К сожелению, ето не помогло(